# Adding double and triple integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

As I know, we can easily add single integrals as follows: $$\int_a^bfdx + \int_b^cfdx = \int_a^cfdx  $$
However, I'm not sure how this works for double and triple integrals? For example, suppose I have a discontinuous volume that I want to find with the following bounds:

- z: $x^2 \to 3-y$
- x: $-\sqrt3 \to -1$ and $1 \to \sqrt3$
- y: $0 \to 2$

Can I write this as the triple integral: 
$$\int_0^2 \int_{-\sqrt3}^{-1} \int_{x^2}^{3-y} f dzdxdy + \int_0^2 \int_{1}^{\sqrt3} \int_{x^2}^{3-y} f dzdxdy $$

Comment: You surely can. Integrals over disjoint regions add up.